# How to make ion-list with visible scrollbar?

Tags: html, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and use ion-list to display number of 
records. when i scroll ion-list then scrollbar display but i want to visible scrollbar every time in ion-list ?

[Here is ion-list docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list)

Comment: Please Share your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content padding style="overflow:scroll">
  <ion-list style="height: 1000px">
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

To make scroller always visible you need to tune "overflow" css property.
Also your list's height should exceed the view port.

Comment: Not Working sir.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like this. It may not be the answer, but it's a much healthier way of defining the height than just giving it a pixel value.

```
<ion-list style="height: auto;">
   <ion-item  *ngFor="let data of datas">
      <ion-label> {{data}} </ion-label>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```